# Definition of size_t for Code composer studio

Tags: c++, arduino, code-composer

I am trying to import arduino library to Code composer studio IDE. I imported it successfully, but i am getting some errors relating to size_t is not a type. I am aware that it has been defined in stddef.h header file. But i am not sure what has to be done to remove this error. To be precise what are the different ways of defining it and what all the header files to be included? So if anyone can help it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: put some code please

Comment: I mean you are asking me to put the complete code of mine or size_t definition code. Because as far as the main code is concerned it has no errors. The only error is from the arduino libraries

Comment: put the full error message than

Comment: #760 variable "size_t" is not a type name

Comment: the whole message , including what  module, what file, what line and update your answer

Comment: So what translation unit (.cpp file) is giving the error.  What header files does that file include.  Why can't you show us a minimal example like `#include <arduino.h> int main() { return 0; }`?  In fact, if you do that, you might find your own answer.

Comment: The string.h file of the arduino library. The whole error states this way
Description :#760 variable "size_t" is not a type name                     Path : .ccsproject /pinInterrupt_CC2650DK_TI_CC2650F128     line 113,  C/C++ Problem

Comment: you can use size_t correctly, but when you include arduiono, it does not work?

Comment: Yep!! I mean to tell when i have imported Arduino libraries to CCS, then it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little information you provided, it is hard to tell what is the problem. However, I may give you some guesses:

`size_t` is platform dependable type. It is the exactly the type that returns by `sizeof` operator.

So when you are using Arduino, it may has another definition or it contract to the one defined by your compiler. I have googled this problem and I found this two solution:

1. Include `Arduino.h` in the cpp you are working with not just the header.
2. In `physfs.h`, add this `#include <stdlib.h>`

Anyway, do you really want to use `size_t` directly? if you are looking for `unsigned long` you can use it directly.. size_t is a bit ambiguous type. For example, on `Windows`,`Intel`, it will have different size for `x86` and `x64` which may cause some problems especially if you are doing some level operation on it.

EDIT: if you are using size_t for the right purpose of it which is size of an object, you should stay using it. My note was just if you are using size_t whenever an unsigned long is needed.

Comment: `size_t` is the correct size to use to represent the size of an object. It's *supposed* to be defined differently on different platforms.

Comment: @KeithThompson absolutly right. but I am afraid that the OP is using it just when unsigned long  is needed.

Comment: What are the different ways to define it? I have checked it on Code composer studio and code blocks. It shows the same error.